# C# Event name is null

Tags: c#, events

I have a WinForms application wherein I have my main application with a separate class that is part of the solution.   In the class which is defining a User control with Dev Express buttons, I have defined my event delegate, event, method and eventargs.

In the main program, i have defined my listener.

I am getting a null value in my event method and cannot see why.  I have reviewed this a number of times and as far as I can see, it is completely correct.

I would appreciate any comments/corrections that would be useful here.

This is the code in my class.

```
public partial class XtraUserControl1 : XtraUserControl, IAnyControlEdit
{
    public delegate void ButtonClickedEventHandler(object sender, ClickEventArgs e);
    public event ButtonClickedEventHandler ButtonClicked;

    public XtraUserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void OnButtonClicked(ClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ButtonClicked != null)
        {
            ButtonClicked(this, e);
        }
    }

    public class ClickEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public readonly SimpleButton buttonClicked;
        public ClickEventArgs(SimpleButton button)
        {
            this.buttonClicked = button;
        }
    }
```

This is the main code where I have defined the listener.

```
private void frmEHHeaders_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create the button group from the User Control XtraUserControl1  and add it to the grid repository
    btnGroup  = new User_Controls.XtraUserControl1();
    RepositoryItemAnyControl riAny = new RepositoryItemAnyControl();
    riAny.Control = btnGroup;
    grdEHHeaders.RepositoryItems.Add(riAny);
    colButtons.ColumnEdit = riAny;

    // Add event handlers
    this.grdEHHeaders.Views[0].MouseDown += gridView1_MouseDown;
    gridView1.CustomRowCellEdit += GridView1_CustomRowCellEdit;

    // Listener for the button class
    btnGroup.ButtonClicked += new User_Controls.XtraUserControl1.ButtonClickedEventHandler(btnGroup_ButtonClicked);
    GetData();
}




private void btnGroup_ButtonClicked(object sender, User_Controls.XtraUserControl1.ClickEventArgs e )
{
    SimpleButton myButton = e.buttonClicked;
    MessageBox.Show("You clicked " + myButton.Text);
}
```

Comment: *"I am getting a null value in my event method"* -- what is null? Which method is your "event method"?

Comment: When asking questions if your problem involves an exception including the full details of the exception including type, message and stack trace is pretty much mandatory. And of course translating the line numbers in the stack trace to indicate relevant parts of code also helps.

Comment: I am not getting an exception of any kind.

Comment: The event method seems quite obvious to me.  In the first code snippet the method is OnButtonClicked.   The test of the Event named ButtonClicked as being not null is the problem in that the value of ButtonClicked event is null.

Comment: @user1238906 *"The event method seems quite obvious to me"* -- nobody asked how obvious it was to you. I have no way of guessing what some random stranger means by "event method". You have two event handlers in your code. You could as easily have meant one of those. "Event name is null" is no help because it makes no sense. But now that you've taken the trouble to identify the problem, it's obvious to me that the event has no handlers. Try giving it one.